# Get apiKey to firebase

Tags: angularjs, cordova, ionic-framework, firebase, angularfire

I need get apiKey to firebase app.

In documentation the example is:

```
var config = {
      apiKey: '<your-api-key>',
      authDomain: '<your-auth-domain>',
      databaseURL: 'https://tecki.firebaseio.com/',
      storageBucket: '<your-storage-bucket>'
    };
firebase.initializeApp(config);
```

and look in the console, documentation and not where to find it .

Answer (score 20):

Here's how I found it:

1. Go to: https://console.firebase.google.com/
2. Under `Projects using Firebase` click on the project you want to get the config for or click "Create new Project"
3. Click the red `Add Firebase to your web app` button. See image below. [Add Firebase to your web app button](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OLwpU.png)

Hope that helps.

Good luck.

Comment: Note: I had to click the [ADD APP button](http://i.imgur.com/pTXOTqm.png) in between step 2 and 3. Possibly only necessary if you have other apps set up already.

Answer (score 10):

[image: it is very easy to find. you can find your api key here. go to your firebase project and do 1,2,3 here]

it is very easy to find. you can find your api key here.  go to your firebase project and do 1,2,3 here

Answer (score 0):

You can see that by going to project overview section

click on the setting button => go to project setting

here you can find the apikey